# zsh - Determine which program is sourcing .zshrc?

Tags: macos, zsh

I have a very large `~/.zshrc` file and `zsh` is my default shell on Mac. When launching VS Code from GUI, VS Code uses the `.zshrc` file to get the env vars. Since VS Code only needs the env vars, not the aliases and functions, is it possible to evaluate which program is sourcing the `.zshrc` file in the `.zshrc` so that the alias and function definitions are skipped when it's VS Code sourcing the file?

Feedback to @jimtut 's answer: `[[ -o login ]]` or `[[ -o interactive]]` don't work in this case. I guess VS Code did initiate an interactive login shell to get the env vars.

I added this in my .zshrc:

```bsh
if [[ -o login ]] && [[ -o interactive ]]; then
    /usr/local/bin/terminal-notifier -message 'login: true\ninteractive: true'
fi
```

and I see the notification from `terminal-notifier` when launching VS Code from the GUI.

More info about VS Code and the env vars: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_resolving-shell-environment-is-slow-error-warning

Comment: This is an interesting question. I know of VS Code only its name, so first two questions from me: 1) VS Code is not just parsing the output of "env" which it gets by invoking a new shell instance for example? 2) Why is it a problem that VS Code ready the whole .zshrc file?

Comment: @mpy 1) I think it is as of version 1.52.1 2) My .zshrc file is super long and it takes zsh ~10 seconds to initiate, and version 1.52.1 of VS Code would abort the process if it's not done within 10s and VS Code won't be able to read important env vars like $PATH.

Comment: I see... 10 seconds are really long.

Answer (score 1):

One way I would investigate further is to include a "logging command" to my `.zshrc`, something like that:

```
{ date
  print -n process:; cat /proc/$$/cmdline
  print
  print -n parent:; cat /proc/$PPID/cmdline
  print
  print ++++++++++++++
} >>| ~/zshrc-log
```

With that little snoop you get a logfile containing the date, the command line of the current process (`$$` holds the pid of the current process) and the command line of the parent (i.e. invoking) process (`$PPID` is the parent pid).

Maybe that is already enough to figure out what is going on. Then you can use a test to check `/proc/$PPID/cmdline` if the sourcing of the file should be aborted at some point (after which only functions / alias are coming) when invoked by VS Code.

This is assumed you have the `/proc` file system available. If not but have the `ps` command at hand, you might try

```
{ date; ps -o pid,args $$ $PPID } >>| ~/zshrc-log
```

which is also shorter, so maybe generally preferrable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I use both macOS & Linux but mostly macOS nowadays. Is there a similar approach that doesn't involve the procfs?

Comment: @TeddyC: I added the `macos` tag to your question to clarify for future readers. I unfortunately don't know this OS, but nevertheless expanded my answer with another approach -- as a blind shot. It might be working also on MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

I use `tcsh`, not any of the Bourne shell derivatives (really, the original `sh` was horrible for your interactive shell, so I've been in the `csh` family for a LONG time).

In `tcsh`, you can do this:

```
if ( $?prompt ) then
  # setup your complicated things that only YOU need interactively
endif
```

I had to Google how to do this in `zsh`, and of course found the answer on another Stack site: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110737/how-would-i-detect-a-non-login-shell-in-zsh

```
if [[ -o interactive ]]; then
  echo "I'm interactive"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However it doesn't work for VS Code. See the edited answer. :)

Comment: That’s too bad it didn’t work. If the other answer about `/proc` and `ps` doesn’t work, maybe send a bug/feature-request to MS to get them to use a non-interactive shell, or at least allow an option for that.